# error while installing cucumber gem on windows 7

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber, rubymine

I am trying to use cucumber with RybyMine.I followed the steps in this link "http://www.guru99.com/cucumber-installation.html" to install.I have installed ruby 1.9.3 p484 and the devkit that goes with it.I have confirmed that ruby is installed.But when I try to initialize devkit from command prompt I see the error "... is not recognized as an internal or external command". I see similar error when trying to install cucumber (2.1.0). I had the devkit already and i was successfully able to use it along with selenium-webdriver(ruby). Am l I missing any step here ?

Comment: Is there any reason why you're using a historical version of Ruby? 1.9 is no longer supported, so newer gems may not work with it.

Comment: I installed this a few months back when I was working with selenium webdriver

Comment: It was wickedly out of date even a few months ago, that version is from 2013. If you can use 2.3.0, that's the most current and you should have fewer issues with it.

Comment: Let me try that. Does any one have the actual steps to install selenium-cucumber with rubymine ?